# How to connect nodejs redis client to redis cloud server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

```js
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
  host: 'redis-19606.redislabs.com',
  port: 19606,
  password: 'password'
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('redis is connected');
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('redis is disconnected: ', err);
});

(async () => {
  try {
    await client.connect();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error while connecting redis', error);
  }
})();
```

This somehow does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? It keeps connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379 which is the default config instead of what I am passing. This is only happening with nodejs client of redis. go-redis the golang client for redis is working flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but which Node Redis version do you use? I had difficulties upgrading myself. The configuration of the client has changed since version 4.x.x. Since version 4.x.x you have to use a confiuration according to [Client Configuration](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/client-configuration.md). Therefore use

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    host: 'redis-19606.redislabs.com',
    port: 19606,
  }
});
```

or use a URL

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  url: "redis://redis-19606.redislabs.com:19606"
});
```

Your client configuration matches the Node Redis version 3.x.x but not 4.x.x. Please see [Redis NPM v3.1.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis/v/3.1.2) and [Redis NPM v4.0.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis/v/4.0.1) for details.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `socket` option. The redis docs (https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/references/client_references/client_nodejs/) is not right. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

you should maintain this format of Redis connecting string:

```
redis://:YOUR_PASSWORD@YOUR_ENDPOINT:YOUR_PORT
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What version of redis are you using?
2. Do not explicitly conect to redis by writing "client.connect()" but
   instead use this after setting host, port and password:

   ```
   redisClient.on("connect", () => {})
   ```

and then you can use **redisClient** variable to get and set values.

3. Also if you're trying to connect to a redislabs server then I think your host name might be incorrect and double check your host from redislabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `new Redis("redis://username:authpassword@127.0.0.1:6380/4");`

Check the documentation [Link](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)